# Backward substitution of a difference equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I was trying to understand the intuition behind this. I understand how the following reccurence was done:

$$X_{t} = \alpha  X_{t-1} + C^{2}$$
$$ \alpha X_{t-1} = \alpha X_{t-2} + C^{2} $$
$$ \alpha^{2} X_{t-2} = \alpha X_{t-3} + C^{2}$$ 
$$... $$
$$\alpha^{t-1} X_{1} = \alpha X_{0} + C^{2}$$

What I don't understand is how do we go from that to this: 
$$X_{t} = \alpha C^{2} + \alpha^{2} C^{2} + \alpha^{3} C^{2} + ... + \alpha^{t-1} C^{2} + \alpha^{t}X_{0}$$

What's the logic here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be:
$$\begin{align}X_t=&\alpha X_{t-1}+C^2=\\
&=\alpha(\alpha X_{t-2}+C^2)+C^2=\\
&=\alpha^2(\alpha X_{t-3}+C^2)+\alpha C^2+C^2=\cdots=\\
&=\alpha^tX_0+(\alpha^{t-1}+\alpha^{t-2}+\cdots+1)C^2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. What do you think about my comment on the other answer?

Comment: I assume you miscopied or there is misprint. The second equation must be $\alpha X_{t-1}=\alpha^2 X_{t-2}+\alpha C^2$. When the first and second equations are added, the term $\alpha X_{t-1}$ cancel out. And so on...

Comment: I get the gist of it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note: as written, your expression is slightly wrong, It should be $X_{t} = C^2+\alpha C^{2} + \alpha^{2} C^{2} + \alpha^{3} C^{2} + ... + \alpha^{t-1} C^{2} + \alpha^{t}X_{0}$

Our recurrence is the first order linear recurrence:

$X_k=\alpha X_{k-1} +C^2 \quad\forall k\geq 1 $

In practice, for fixed t we can find the given expression by substituting the recurrence "t times". Formally, we can prove your claim by induction:

The base case is clear: $X_1=C^2+\alpha X_0$

Suppose $X_{t} = C^2 +\alpha C^{2} + \alpha^{2} C^{2} + \alpha^{3} C^{2} + ... + \alpha^{t-1} C^{2} + \alpha^{t}X_{0}$ for some fixed t.
Then, by our recurrence,

$X_{t+1}= \alpha X_t +C^2 = C^2 +\alpha(C^2+\alpha C^{2} + \alpha^{2} C^{2} + ... + \alpha^{t-1} C^{2} + \alpha^{t}X_{0})  = C^2 + \alpha C^2 + \cdots \alpha^t C^2 +\alpha^{t+1} X_0$

which is what we wanted to show.

Thus, our claim holds true by mathematical induction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. What confuses me is in this application they piled the recursion just like I typed, then proceeded to simplify (cancel out) multiple terms then just summed what remained to get that final answer. It's this approach that I'm trying to understand. Thanks in advance.